# Element Under JQUERY UI Datepicker Gets 'Clicked' When User Clicks Calendar Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an HTML Input Type=Text with a date that is enhanced with the JQUERY UI Datepicker option such that a calendar pops up when the user clicks the input.  When the calendar pops up, it 'sits' on top of a JQUERY MOBILE Select.  If a user clicks a day in the calendar that is directly above the select element, the calendar accepts the new date and closes but the select list simultaneously opens to display the options.  In other words, the select list is responding to a click generated when the user clicks the overlying calendar.

I need to 'turn off' click listening to the select list when the input field has focus.  How can I do that or is there a better way to address the problem?

```
aString = '<input type="text" id="aDate" value="12/10/2015"/>';
aString += '<select name="aSelect" id="aSelectID">';
aString += '<option value="1">1</option>';
aString += '<option value="2">2</option>';
aString += '</select>'
$('#pg1').empty();
$('#pg1').append(aString).enhanceWithin();
$('#aDate').datepicker();
```

That's the relevant snippet.  The page displays the input box for the date and a select list under the input box.  When the date field is clicked, a calendar pops up over the select list.  When the user clicks a date that happens to overlay the select list, the calendar closes and the select list opens.

ETA:  With a JQUERY Mobile selectbox, when the mouse hovers over the box, the box changes it's color shade.  When the calendar is open, the select box still changes color when the mouse is over the select box even though the calendar is in the way.  It has something to do with JQUERY Mobile not "knowing" that a JQUERY UI element has popped in front the JQM element.

Comment: Can you supply a codesnippet or fiddle for this?